# Logo Squashed in Chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, css

When I signed into chat today, the logo at the bottom-right looks like this.

[image]

[Marco Ceppi](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/41) commented on it:

> I know they did some changes to chat yesterday to fix the API - there may have also been a design update to take care of other desgin bugs too which could have inadvertently broke that CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that had nothing to do with the API changes; it was actually a side effect of factoring out repeated code. Lesson learned: DRY is good, but do it right :)

Fixed now.